# Getting Go-ahead From Team Leader

Tags: communication, management, career-development, politics

Another team leader at the company I work for has been using a tool and has claimed to have great success with it. The team I'm working on could also use this tool but it may require some adjustments to how we do things but more importantly, approval from my team leader. The company has quite a few layers of approval before anything can get the go ahead. The upper manager has spoken to me about wanting to integrate this tool with our team and I stated that it is my team leader that needs to approve it.

How I can properly suggest this to my team leader while at the same time letting upper management know that I tried while avoiding office politics and demonstrating to management that I'm doing a good job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How I can properly suggest this to my team leader ?

"`Hey, boss, team X is using tool Y and it saves them Z hours every week`". It's as simple as that.

Do it in a chat, wait for a team meeting, send an email - only you know your boss & company culture, so only you can decide how to say it - but that's what to say.

If you present a clear benefit (minus the cost of adjusting it for your team), your boss will hopefully want to go ahead. If not, then you have a new question for us :-)

Comment: And, be patient. It sometimes takes people a while to absorb and act on this kind of advice.